# Virtualenv: workon command not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, virtualenv

I have installed virtualenv and the virtualwrapper via apt-get, I got to a point where I created a virtual enviroment but however later on during that same day when I used the workon command it was not found. I further on went and inspected my home directory and .virtualenvs dir and the virtualenv I created earlier were still there.

Answer (score 65):

Solving this problem took two steps:

Add this to your `.bashrc` / `.bash_profile` / `.zshrc`:

```
# load virtualenvwrapper for python (after custom PATHs)
venvwrap="virtualenvwrapper.sh"
/usr/bin/which -s $venvwrap
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    venvwrap=`/usr/bin/which $venvwrap`
    source $venvwrap
fi
```

Then use:

```
source .bash_profile
# or .bashrc / .zshrc
```

to reflect the changes.

Additionally, if the terminal still sometimes cant find `workon`, use `source .bash_profile` to reset and find it again.

Comment: Thanks. In Mint 17.x it didn't like the -s on the which so I switched it for -a (which I think corresponds to -s) and now it works.

Comment: I had to use `-a` instead of `-s` as well on Ubuntu. May be the case for Debian-based systems I guess.

Answer (score 17):

type [`source .profile`](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do) in home directory from terminal.

Answer (score 16):

Read the readme in the top of `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`
You need to source it inside bashrc

Answer (score 11):

open ~/.profile

```
cd ~
nano .profile
```

add at the end

```
#virtualenvwrapper setup
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/envs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/dev
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

to load your .profile file you just edited:

```
$ . .profile
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to this problem too and I simply needed to logout and log back in.
This read in the changes which the debian package manager made to my system at /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper