# How to fix broken python 2.7.11 after OSx updates? An in-depth look into Homebrew and beyond

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, homebrew

## What happened:

After an OSx update and installing a new version of `python 2.7` my `virtualevn` environment completely broke and I struggled in fixing it. I wasn't sure what caused it and went through a whole set of things that I did and read initially that **didn't work** are listed below. What solved my problem is provided in the answer section.

### What didn't work to fix `virtualenv` command not found:

- Installed python through homebrew and then used pip to install virtualenv
- Installed python through https://www.python.org and then used pip to install virtualenv

Related questions that helped me but did not provide the solution to my problem:

1. [virtualenv-command-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133050/virtualenv-command-not-found)
2. [virtualenv-workon-command-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928555/virtualenv-workon-command-not-found)

### Complete manual recovery I went through (What not to do!):

This didn't completely solved my problem. It is just to give you an idea of what steps I went through before I found the correct way to fix my python dev environment on my OSx.

- Removed python 2.7 by using the post in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4)
- Removed the homebrew installed version
- Installed python through the pkg file in [Mac OS X 32-bit i386/PPC installer](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.10/python-2.7.10-macosx10.5.pkg) or [Mac OS X 64-bit/32-bit installer](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.10/python-2.7.10-macosx10.6.pkg)
- Manually installed virtualenv following the instructions from [here](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html):

  ```
   curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-13.1.2.tar.gz
   tar xvfz virtualenv-13.1.2.tar.gz 
   cd virtualenv-13.1.2 
   sudo python setup.py install
  ```
- Manaully install `pip` through [7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585875/what-is-the-official-preferred-way-to-install-pip-and-virtualenv-systemwide?lq=1):
       curl --silent --show-error --retry 5 https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python2.7

#### PIP was still broken after all this:

After all this after creating a virtual environment my pip still installed the packages in the main python folder instead of installing them under the virtual environment and non of the threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607837/pip-install-not-installing-into-correct-directory) neither [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952797/pip-installing-in-global-site-packages-instead-of-virtualenv) helped. My solution to that was to run pip under my virtual env with the following options:
1- Activate the virtual environment so that `$VIRTUAL_ENV` is set:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

2- Forces pip to install in the right destination:

```
pip install --target=$VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

### Summary

Something was badly broken and best way I fix my dev environment is provided in the answer to this question.

Comment: I just had this issue after restoring from Time Machine and upgrading to the latest version of Sierra. Anything that used python resulted in the error `python --version
Illegal instruction: 4`, after reinstalling it seems to be working again.

Comment: find a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372911/python-pip-error-on-osx/47832840#47832840

Answer (score 50, accepted):

## The reason

In my case was an OSx upgrade that affected my homebrew and after upgrading to python 2.7.11 is didn't install it properly.

## How I got it to work:

I found steps 3 and 4 in a thread [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/40516) and many thanks to https://github.com/baronomasia.

1 - Removed python 2.7 by using the post in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4)

2 - Removed the homebrew python installed version

```
brew uninstall python
```

3- Reinstall your Xcode command tools:

```
sudo xcode-select --install
```

4- Upgrade homebrew and reinstall python through homebrew:

```
brew update && brew reinstall python
```

Comment: For the step 2, I had to add --force flag. i.e. brew uninstall python --force

Comment: I tried this trying to fix my "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1" error when-ever i run pip2 to but it doesn't seem to have worked. don't know if anyone else is still getting this broken pip issue?

Comment: Also, to remove the symlinks you can use this command:

`cd /usr/local/bin/`
then, 
`ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7' | awk '{print $9}' | tr -d @ | xargs rm`

Answer (score 3):

After doing `brew upgrade python` my system python was broken and was throwing fits about virtualenvwrapper.sh, as well as my `pip` command was just suddenly missing.
I went to python.org and downloaded the python 2.7.13 installer, ran it, I now have python 2.7.13, pip, and can run `pip install virtualenvwrapper` and things seem to work.