# Working with 2 pythons on same machine

Tags: python, linux

I installed Linux Mint as Virtual Machine.
When I do:

```
python --version
```

I get:

```
Python 2.7.6
```

I installed seperate python folder acording to [this](http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/18641/Upgrade-Python-2-7-6-to-Python-2-7-10-on-Linux-Mint-OS.html).
and When I do:

```
python2.7 --version
```

I get:

```
Python 2.7.11
```

Now, I want to work only on Python 2.7.11

I installed pip
and installed a package using pip with `pip install paypalrestsdk`
It was successfull:

[image]

However when I run the script using this package I get:
[image]

i suspect that pip and the install were done on the `python 2.7.6` rather than the `python 2.7.11`
What can I do?

Comment: wouldn't it just be easier using virtualenvs?

Comment: It's funny how your screenshots suggest you're reading [this page](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/issues/117)

Answer (score 0):

Since you get the right Python version by running `python2.7`, you could use `pip2.7` to install packages in it:

```
pip2.7 install paypalrestsdk
```

Comment: If you don't have the symlink, you can always specify the full path: `/path/to/correct/version/pip install paypalrestsdk`

Comment: I think the pip itself is not installed in the new version. How do I install it there?

Answer (score 0):

Use virtual environment http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ to manage different versioned libraries. Install the wanted libraries in the environment created.

```
mkvirtualenv myenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.6 
workon myenv
pip install paypalrestsdk
```

Comment: You need to add virtualenvwrapper.sh to your path
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928555/virtualenv-workon-command-not-found

Answer (score 0):

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python2.7 get-pip.py
```

Using this pip install:

```
pip install paypalrestsdk
```

Good luck!